# Replace querystring attribute value in java using regex

Tags: java, regex, query-string

I want to replace querystring value but it's creating some problems:

**Problem 1**: Its Removing the "&" symbol after replacing

```
String queryString = "?pid=1&name=Dell&cid=25";
String nQueryString=queryString.replaceAll("(?<=[?&;])pid=.*?($|[&;])","pid=23");
System.out.println(nQueryString);
```

**output of above example** 
`?pid=23name=Dell&cid=25`

you can see its removed the "&" after `pid`

**Problem 2**: Its not working if I removed the "?" symbol from the `queryString` variable.

```
String queryString = "pid=1&name=Dell&cid=25";
String nQueryString=queryString.replaceAll("(?<=[?&;])pid=.*?($|[&;])","pid=23");
System.out.println(nQueryString);
```

**output of above example** 
`?pid=1&name=Dell&cid=25`

We can say the regex is not working, So anyone can suggest me better regex which completely fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queryString.replaceAll("(?<=[?&;])pid=.*?(?=[&;])", "pid=23")
```

Difference is that I'm using a positive-lookahead: `(?=[&;])`, which is zero-length, making it atomic, and is not actually included in the replacement via `replaceAll()`, just like your original positive-lookbehind is not replaced.

Alternatively, we can match until a `&` or `;` is found, but not included in the replacement, ie:

```
queryString.replaceAll("(?<=[?&;])pid=[^&;]*", "pid=23")
```

`[^&;]` : `^` negates the following: `&;`, so `[^&;]*` will match until a `;` or `&` is encountered.

Yours does not work because `($|[&;])` is a non-atomic group, specifically a capturing group, and thus is included in the replacement.  NB: a non-capturing group `(?:$|[&;])` would also fail here.

To your final note, you're using a positive look-behind for `?`, `&`, and `;`, so by removing the `?`, it will no longer match, which makes sense.

Comment: Yes @Steve you are right, but when I was trying to replace the same queryString with blank space then its not removing "&" symbol.
`queryString.replaceAll("(?<=[?&;])pid=[^&]*","")` will give
`?&name=Dell&cid=25`

Comment: Oh yes, I just wanted to replace the queryString values, but I just tried to replace the attribute. I would be better if the same regex will work for me, that's why I tried and commented. Thanks @Steve, your answer is very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `regex` instead:

```
String nQueryString = queryString.replaceAll("(?<=[?&;])pid=[^&]*", "pid=23");
//=> ?pid=23&name=Dell&cid=25
```

Here `[^&]*` is called `negation matching pattern`, that will match query string value until `&` is found OR else end of string is found thus leaving rest of the query string un-effected.